# Notification throws error when using vector drawables

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, android-notifications, android-appcompat

I get the following exception when I use a vector drawable to set the small icon for a notification :

> android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package com.qbes.xxx: Couldn't create icon: StatusBarIcon(pkg=com.qbes.xxxuser=0 id=0x7f020082 level=0 visible=true num=0 )

Here is my code :

```
mNotificationBuilder = new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setDefaults(android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)
                .setSound(null)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_white)
                .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
                .setCategory(android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_PROGRESS)
                .setContentTitle("Trip in Progress...")
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setProgress(0, 0, progress)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setPriority(android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

mNotificationBuilder.setContentText(body);

mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification note = mNotificationBuilder.build();

mNotificationManager.notify(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID_Dash, note);
```

and my `build.gradle` (only relevant parts) :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.qbes.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 720
        versionName "0.7.20"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
}
```

PS : The code works fine when I use a png or jpg image drawable, but breaks when using a vector drawable.

I have been searching for a whole day but could not find anything that worked for me. Any Ideas.

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on? You are using the support library backport in general, but I don't think that will work for a `Notification`, since the platform is the one trying to use the resource.

Comment: I am testing on API 19. I'll check if the issue exists in any other versions.

Comment: Ive put the check for sdk version, and avoid calling setSmallIcon for versions earlier than api version 21 Kitkat

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You are using the vector drawable support package. That's fine, but that only works in your app. The platform does not know how to use vector drawables prior to API Level 21, and for a `Notification`, the platform is the one rendering the resource.

You could render the vector drawable yourself to a `Canvas` backed by a `Bitmap`, then use that `Bitmap` in the `Notification`. Or, you could use the vector backport library in general, but for your handful of `Notification` icons, generate PNG files for them and use them on the older devices. [Put the corresponding vector drawables in `res/drawable-anydpi-v21/`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/12/21/nodpi-anydpi-wtf.html), and the newer devices will use the vector drawables while older devices fall back to the PNGs.

Comment: one more thing. what is the preferred dp size for the small icon?

Comment: @ShahiM: `24dp`, I think.

Comment: why using vectors again when pngs is there for older devices?!

Comment: Is it same with Launcher icons too?

Comment: @SeshuVinay: Yes, in that you cannot assume that the home screen implementation knows how to use vector drawables. I tried this and ran into a variety of problems.

Comment: Excellent solution. I used hard-coded java to use a midmap instead of a xml (vector) icon for APIs < 21 but I like your solution even better! Thanks !