# How to use xml icons in android 4.4 and lower?

Tags: android, icons

I want to use a flat icon to notify in the status bar, I use a xml-resource. For devices with versions of android 5.0 and above everything works, on 4.4 and 4.2 the application falls with an error

```
03-22 19:21:39.441 2221-2221/org.odk.collect.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: org.odk.collect.android, PID: 2221
                                                                     android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package org.odk.collect.android: Couldn't create icon: StatusBarIcon(pkg=org.odk.collect.androiduser=0 id=0x7f0800b1 level=0 visible=true num=0 )
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I set a material icon on android versions below 5.0?

Comment: `implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1"`

Comment: @Chisko i already have this dependency, but app is still crushes

Comment: Is your xml icon a vector drawable? As far as I know, it's not possible to use vector drawables as notification icons on pre-Lollipop devices. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39382225