# Can we use SVG file as a notification icon in Android

Tags: android, push-notification

when I use a Vector drawable (54x54) it works fine. Similarly when I replace the vector drawable with SVG of same size (it doesn't matter I guess), it doesn't show up in the notification bar instead it shows a default icon.

Comment: I believe you questioned is answered in [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34016107/can-we-use-vectordrawable-or-vectorxml-as-icons-for-push-notifications-in-androi)

Comment: If I am not wrong, It talks about the vector drawables which is working for me :)

Comment: SVG as in the raw svg file? If it is, then android cannot use it directly, you have to convert it to a vector drawable.

Comment: oops!! yes it is a raw svg file, thanks for the information

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE 2020

You can now use a .svg file. Or well... At least you can drop a .svg file in Android Studio and it will take care of generating all the correct files for all Android versions.

Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62876054/8634342